# As of late 2020, is optane still worth considering?

Tags: hard-drive, ssd, hardware-rec, nvme, optane

If I want very fast NVMe storage for general usage, is Optane still a good option?
In the past, I read that Optane/3D Xpoint was superior in situations that didn't just require raw throughput, mainly due to its very high IOPS, however as of late 2020 the best Optane M.2 drives are rated at 300000+ IOPS read, 250000 4k IOPS write and roughly 3GBps sequential read and 1.6GBps sequential writes, as opposed to a 980 PRO which is rated at 800k/1000k IOPS at 7GB read/5GB write, and there are even affordable PCIe 3.x drives that surpass Optane in these metrics by quite a bit.
My question is if these metrics tell the whole story and if Optane is now obsolete as a high end NVMe storage medium or if there is something I am overlooking that might make it worth a look as a boot drive or a cache drive?

Comment: Are you looking for a cache or storage SSD?

Comment: A cache or a small boot drive for linux. So my specific use case is that I want to upgrade my (AMD) laptop's storage, but I have two nvme slots and I'm considering populating both.

Comment: Linux doesn’t support Intel RST which is required for Optane. Now you can use it as a normal storage drive.  However, Optane drives are designed for a cache function, that requires Intel RST.

Comment: So using them as anything but a cache drive yields no advantage? Are you sure I can't use it with linux, I could just use it as a zfs cache?

Comment: https://codenotary.io/blog/ubuntu-how-to-use-intel-optane-memory-for-ssd-caching/

Comment: You don’t need an Optane drive to accomplish what that article describes.